# Text only floats left one line next to image

Tags: html, css

Deleted all the extra stuff, all I want is the row to **float left** so there is some text next to the image, but it only moves over one line. Using bootstrap if that helps, along with my own **CSS** file.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPfii.png)

```
<!--main body container -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">   
      <h1>About Me</h1>
    </div>  
    <div id="bio" class="row">
      <img src= "assets/images/linkedin-logo.png" alt="default photo">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dapibus orci nisl, ut maximus eros congue commodo. Vivamus fermentum dictum erat. Fusce feugiat maximus nulla, eget scelerisque eros sodales vel. Ut vehicula velit nisl, et tempor justo blandit in. Morbi a elit eleifend, efficitur felis sed, pellentesque risus. Praesent quis ante et massa vehicula efficitur. Cras id tortor et elit ornare bibendum non non arcu. Sed lectus enim, consectetur eget pretium in, tempus et quam. Suspendisse elementum porttitor elementum. Donec egestas lectus gravida risus convallis consectetur.
    </div>  
  </div>
<!--Main Container End-->   
</div>
```

**css code:**

```
#bio {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float your image to the left

```
 #bio img {
     float: left;
 }
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/L75dhtny/

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
<!--main body container -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">   
                <h1>About Me</h1>
            </div>  
            <div id="bio" class="row">
                <img src= "assets/images/linkedin-logo.png" alt="default photo">

            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br> Etiam dapibus orci nisl, ut maximus eros congue commodo. Vivamus fermentum dictum erat. Fusce feugiat maximus nulla, eget scelerisque eros sodales vel. Ut vehicula velit nisl, et tempor justo blandit in. Morbi a elit eleifend, efficitur felis sed, pellentesque risus. Praesent quis ante et massa vehicula efficitur. Cras id tortor et elit ornare bibendum non non arcu. Sed lectus enim, consectetur eget pretium in, tempus et quam. Suspendisse elementum porttitor elementum. Donec egestas lectus gravida risus convallis consectetur.
            </div>  
    </div>
<!--Main Container End-->   
</div>
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/rr0ywybm/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```css
/* css code */        
    img {
        float: left;
        padding:2px;
        margin-right:4px;
    }
```

```html
<!--main body container -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">   
                <h1>About Me</h1>
            </div>  
            <div id="bio" class="row">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">

            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dapibus orci nisl, ut maximus eros congue commodo. Vivamus fermentum dictum erat. Fusce feugiat maximus nulla, eget scelerisque eros sodales vel. Ut vehicula velit nisl, et tempor justo blandit in. Morbi a elit eleifend, efficitur felis sed, pellentesque risus. Praesent quis ante et massa vehicula efficitur. Cras id tortor et elit ornare bibendum non non arcu. Sed lectus enim, consectetur eget pretium in, tempus et quam. Suspendisse elementum porttitor elementum. Donec egestas lectus gravida risus convallis consectetur.
            </div>  
    </div>
<!--Main Container End-->   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```